# Exception fetching current thread user in SPUtility.CacheClaimsIdentity

Tags: claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

Has anyone come across this exception? It occurs when I have the mapToWindows web.config value set to true, and I try to authenticate using either Windows Authentication or our custom STS.

```
Exception fetching current thread user in SPUtility.CacheClaimsIdentity: Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.
Parameter name: identity    0.00143314303912927 0.001357
Runtime Tag(tkau) System.ArgumentException: Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.
Parameter name: encodedValue
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String encodedValue)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.GetProviderUserKey(String encodedSuffix)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHeaderManager.AddIsapiHeaders(HttpContext context, String encodedUrl, NameValueCollection headers)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with this for ages, it turns out that the mapToWindows config value is not supported within SharePoint. You have to rely on each part of SharePoint being claims aware and converting the token themselves.